# SSIS stopped working when loading into azure dwh

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssis, oledb

Hope someone can help here.

my SSIS packages (straightforward fetch rows from Azure SQL db ---> load into azure dwh) have suddenly stopped working, after running smoothly for 2 months.

The insert (specilifally OLE DB component) now fails with error message

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>   code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "The source and target columns must be in the same order in the INSERT BULK statement."

Packages are developed with SSDT for VS 2013. No recoding or redeployment of azure dwh , just this error appeared out of the blue one day.

/Dmitri.

Answer (score 0):

I quote [Rick He](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/rick%20%20%20%20%20%20%20he/?ws=usercard-mini):

The issue could be that your database has case insensitive collation and distribution column name specified in the table DDL is "different" from column name in column definition in terms of lower/upper cases.

For example, your original table DDL could be like:

create table tableA (colABC int) with (distribution=hash(colabc))

In this case your BCP(SqlBulkCopy) might stop working recently. This is a product issue. The latest GA release has this issue, and the team is trying to fix this issue now.

Workaround for now: Create a new table to make sure column names are exact the same. Take above example:

create table tableA (colABC int) with (distribution=hash(colABC))